# When does $|P_n(x)|=1$ hold?

Tags: polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

Let $P_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2k} (X^2-1)^k X^{n-2k}$ be the $n$-th Tchebyshev polynomial.

I want to solve $|P_n(x)|=1$ for $x\in [-1,1]$

I checked that $\large\cos\frac{k \pi}{n}$ with $k=0,\ldots,n$ fit, but why are they the only ones ?

I'm quite reluctant to use derivatives (I'd like a more simple argument).

Comment: What is the degree of the polynomial?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $n$ but with the absolute value it's not a polynomial anymore...

Comment: Well, it's easy to turn it into a polynomial equation, $T_n^2(x)-1=0$. But if you want complex roots, that's another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not to hard to prove Valeriy's alternate form.
This proof holds only for $x \in [-1,1]$
because we need $\cos^{-1}(x)$
to exist.
\begin{align*}
\cos(n \cos^{-1}(x))
&= \Re \left[ e^{i n \cos^{-1}(x)} \right] \\
&= \Re
\left[ \left[ \cos (\cos^{-1}(x))  + i \sin(\cos^{-1}(x)) \right]^n \right] \\
&= \Re
\left[ \left[ x  \pm  i \sqrt{1 - x^2} \right]^n \right] \\
&= \sum_{k \ge 0} {n \choose 2k}
\left(\pm i \sqrt{1 - x^2}\right)^{2k} x^{n- 2k} \\
&= \sum_{k \ge 0} {n \choose 2k}
(-1)^k (1 - x^2)^k x^{n- 2k}. \\
\end{align*}

So then
\begin{align*}
|P_n(x)| &= 1 \\
\implies n \cos^{-1}(x) &= k \pi \\
\implies \cos^{-1}(x) &= \frac{k \pi}{n} \\
\implies x &= \cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right). \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You can represent $P_n$ in alternate form: $P_n(x) = \cos(n\cos^{-1}(x))$. Now the roots of two equations for $|P_n(x)| = 1$ could be easily derived.